# SQLITE: Database change are not saved and all entries are deleted instead than one

Tags: sqlite, tkinter

I've created my SQLITE3 database using a tutorial online where the records where loaded in tkinter entries and then saved from there. In the tutorial there was a id_entry that was used for the remove_one, remove_many, remove_all and the update_record function. I've removed that entry and I'm trying to use "rowid" instead, but unfortunly my code is not working:
When using **remove_one**  it is deleted only one record, but when I close my app and restart every record is missing.
**remove_many** and **update_record** actually works, but when I close and I open again the app the changes are not saved.
I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for your help!
P.S.(I've made some change to the code to make it shorter and more understandable, if there is some inconsistency it could be the reason. The code right now does not give me back any kind of error at all)

*Create database*

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('records_list.db')

        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE if not exists records (
            author text,
            year text,
            title text,
            page text,
            """)

        conn.commit()

        conn.close()
```

*Query database*

```
        def query_database():
            global count
            count = 0

            for record in record_tree.get_children():
                record_tree.delete(record)
                
            conn = sqlite3.connect('records_list.db')

            c = conn.cursor()

            c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM records")
            records = c.fetchall()

            for record in records:         
                if count % 2 == 0:
                    record_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], tags=('evenrow',))
                else:
                    record_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], tags=('oddrow',))

                count += 1

            conn.commit()

            conn.close()
```

*Remove many*

```
        def remove_many():
            response = messagebox.askyesno("WOAH!!!!", "This Will Delete EVERYTHING SELECTED From The Table\nAre You Sure?!")

            if response == 1:
                x = record_tree.selection()

                ids_to_delete = []
                
                for record in x:
                    ids_to_delete.append(record_tree.item(record, 'values')[0])

                for record in x:
                    record_tree.delete(record)

                conn = sqlite3.connect('records_list.db')

                c = conn.cursor()
                
                c.executemany("DELETE FROM records WHERE rowid = ?", [(a,) for a in ids_to_delete])

                ids_to_delete = []

                conn.commit()

                conn.close()

                clear_entries()
```

*Remove one*

```
        def remove_one():
            x = record_tree.selection()[0]
            record_tree.delete(x)

            conn = sqlite3.connect('records_list.db')

            c = conn.cursor()

            c.execute("DELETE from records WHERE oid=" + 'rowid')
            
            conn.commit()

            conn.close()

            clear_entries()

            messagebox.showinfo("Deleted!", "Your record Has Been Deleted!")
```

*update_record*

```
        def update_record():
            selected = record_tree.focus()
            record_tree.item(selected, text="", values=(author_entry.get(), year_entry.get(), title_entry.get(), journal_entry.get(), volume_entry.get(), number_entry.get(), page_entry.get(), doi_entry.get(),))

            conn = sqlite3.connect('records_list.db')

            c = conn.cursor()

            c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM records")
            records = c.fetchall()

            c.execute("""UPDATE records SET
                author = :author,
                year = :year,
                title = :title,
                page = :page,


                WHERE oid = :oid""",
                {
                    'author': author_entry.get(),
                    'year': year_entry.get(),
                    'title': title_entry.get(),
                    'page': page_entry.get(),
                    'oid': "rowid",
                })
            
            conn.commit()

            conn.close()

            clear_entries()
```

Comment: You need to provide the actual `rowid` instead of `"rowid"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've fixed the remove_one function changing ```"c.execute("DELETE from records WHERE oid=" + 'rowid')"``` to ```c.execute("DELETE from records WHERE oid=" +  x)```  I've also edited update_record like this  ```'oid': select```   but it still doeasn't work. I'm still trying to figure out how edit the remove_many function

Comment: Did you verify the values of `x` and `select` are the correct *rowid* in the database?

Comment: They don't always match if I delete something. Is there a way yo access the rowid of a selected item? I can't find any solution online. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the value of `x` (result of `record_tree.selection()[0]`) and `selected` (result of `record_tree.focus()`) are not the actual `rowid` in the database.  You need to save the `rowid` to `iid` option when inserting the records into treeview:

```py
c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM records")
records = c.fetchall()

count = 0
for record in records:         
    if count % 2 == 0:
        # record[0] is the rowid
        record_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=record[0], values=(record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4]), tags=('evenrow',))
    else:
        record_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=record[0], values=(record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4]), tags=('oddrow',))

    count += 1
```

Then to delete the selected record in treeview:

```py
...
selected = record_tree.selection()
if selected:
    record_tree.delete(selected[0])
    c.execute('DELETE FROM records WHERE rowid = ?', (selected[0],))
    conn.commit()
    ...
```

Similar logic applies on updating record.